# API rest send array JSON

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to send an array of a record to my client by using an API rest with Laravel.

This is my code:

```
public function index ($id) {
    $gards = DB::table('gards')
    ->whereRaw('date_from < Now() AND date_to > Now() AND (gard_day = 1 OR gard_night = 1)')
    ->get();
   
    foreach($gards as $gard) {
        $id_pharma = $gard->pharmacy_id;
        $pharmacy = DB::table('pharmacies')->whereRaw("id = {$id_pharma} AND city_id = {$id}")->get();
        
        return response()->json($pharmacy, 200);
    }   
}
```

But it sends only the first record.

[image: this is a snapshot of postman]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Issam, this is happening because the return is inside the foreach, you need to put it outside of the foreach, also you may wanna create a variable to hold the value to be returned until it's ready to me returned, so you may wanna create a array before the foreach, populate inside the foreach and return it after the foreach.

Comment: You are returning in your first iteration of your `foreach`... you can simply achieve what you want if you use `relations` instead of using `DB::....`... it is not hard to [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) and really understand it....

Comment: You use `whereRaw()` wrong. Laravel's query builder explicitly offers you secure methods and you purposely are a recipe for sql injections.

Comment: Thank you for these informations, i will try to follow your instructions, ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, you are falling into the n+1 queries dilemma (read more on Google), but basically, you are doing a query for each of the lines in the 'gards' table. This is super inefficient.  There may be a better way to achieve this with relations, but the following solution only executes 2 queries and you get your result.

```
public function index ($id) {
    $ids = DB::table('gards')
        ->whereRaw('date_from < Now() AND date_to > Now() AND (gard_day = 1 OR gard_night = 1)')
        ->pluck('pharmacy_id');
    //The pluck function gets all the pharmacy_id and it assigns them to the $ids variable. 

    $pharmacies = DB::table('pharmacies')
       ->whereIn('id', $ids)
       ->where('city_id', $id)
       ->get();
    
    return response()->json($pharmacies);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are a lifesaver it works just perfectly